# What does "Ayy girl, are you death? 'Cause I want you to take me by surprise." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

So, the other day I was watching TV and someone made a joke (I assume).
The joke was

> Ayy girl, are you death?
>   'Cause I want you to **take me by surprise**.

What does the joke mean?
And if he'd used **'Cause I want you to take me**, would it make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Are you X? Because Y* is a common pickup line, compliment, joke, etc  construction. Y has a double meaning that relates to X and achieves some kind of punchline.

> [take by surprise](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+by+surprise)
>   to startle someone; to surprise someone with something unexpected. *Oh! You took me by surprise because I didn't hear you come in. Bill caught his mother by surprise by coming to the door and pretending to be selling something.*

As you might imagine, death can happen suddenly and take someone by surprise (unexpectedly).

> He was so young. His death took us by surprise.

*Take me* can also mean *have sex with me* (Urban Dictionary: [take me](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Take%20me)). So I reason that in this context, *take me by surprise* more or less means *have sex with me and make it a surprise*, or *surprise me with sex*.

If you change it to *'cause I want you to take me*, it doesn't sound quite right. Perhaps it is because the second option sounds more like a request to die.